# Fill Value of textbox on the basis of other textbox Infopath

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, vsta

i am new to infopath. i want to set the value of textbox b based on the value of other textbox a from SharePoint list. In Infopath vsta, textbox a onchanged event i am setting the value of textbox b which work ok as far as i check through preview on infopath.
But when i deploy this simple form through administration approve template as content type to my sharepoint document library. the form opens in the web browser but on change event of textbox a is not working (asynchronously). instead it works when i hit the submit button. 
 submission logic is to submit this form to document library. 
 in infopath configuration i have given the form full trust level.

Any Idea why its not working as expected. or is this any other solution apart from infopath programming?

Answer (score 0):

Text box properties -> browser forms -> "Always".

Presence of the OnChanged event handler does not trigger postback (which is needed as code runs on server, not in the browser).